# Light UIAlertView/UIActionView customization

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Would this type of customization be considered App Store safe ?

```
UIColor *veBlueColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:3.0/255.0 green:147.0/255.0 blue:215.0/255.0 alpha:1];
UIColor *veRedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:242.0/255.0 green:93.0/255.0 blue:69.0/255.0 alpha:1];

for (UIView *subview in actionSheet.subviews) {

    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

        UIButton *button                    = (UIButton*)subview;
        UIColor *buttonColor                = [button titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSString *buttonColorString         = [buttonColor description];

        UIColor *destructiveColor           = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.992157 green:0.278431 blue:0.168627 alpha:1];
        NSString *destructiveColorString    = [destructiveColor description];

        bool isDestructiveButton            = ([buttonColorString isEqual:destructiveColorString]?YES:NO);

        if (!isDestructiveButton) {

            [button setTitleColor:veBlueColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else {

            [button setTitleColor:veRedColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

I have read the Human Interface Guidelines but there are always "gray areas" and a google search returns quite a few people claiming they got there App approved with customizations that are clearly not allowed by Apple.

So my question is, what are your experiences are with "light" customization ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No in my opinion it's not safe. The Apple documentation clearly states: "UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:."

In this case you're not adding subviews but you're actually retrieving the ones that are already there and customising them - which from an Apple perspective I assume is quite similar.

I would suggest creating your own ActionSheet if the UIActionSheet API is too restrictive for what you need. (I recommend having a look on Git Hub as there are different solutions that might be a good fit for you).

Comment: Thanx, it sounds logical. In any guideline or recommendation, interpretation from one to another can differ but I will go with "better to be safe than sorry"